# Checking to find out if go code has been formatted

Tags: go

My goal is to enforce the formatting of go source code on commit.  Is there a way to find out if running `go fmt` over a file/set of files would make any changes? The only technique I can think of is to:

- store the current time *t*
- run go fmt over the source
- iterate the source files to see if any of the last mod dates > *t*

I could write a tool/script to do this and execute during circle CI build. I wanted to check that I'm not reinventing the wheel before I go ahead.

Comment: Why not format it unconditionally?

Comment: This is built-in to the `gofmt` program: `gofmt -l ...`

Comment: you could always run `md5sum` before and after to be sure the file hasn't changed even if the timestamp has.

Comment: @coredump because if changes were made they would need to be committed which would break the flow; the build job is to assert not mutate

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to `gofmt -h` you can use `-l` option:

> -l    list files whose formatting differs from gofmt's`

Something like:

```
> gofmt -l .
```

And pass the received list of files further.

Answer (score 8):

Add additional info for @u_mulder 's answer.

If you want the exit code be 1 if fails, you can use

```
test -z $(gofmt -l .)
```

This is helpful in CI. However, this won't list the list of different files.

Answer (score 5):

I found [this pre-commit hook](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.12/misc/git/pre-commit):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

gofiles=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep '\.go$')
[ -z "$gofiles" ] && exit 0

unformatted=$(gofmt -l $gofiles)
[ -z "$unformatted" ] && exit 0

# Some files are not gofmt'd. Print message and fail.

echo >&2 "Go files must be formatted with gofmt. Please run:"
for fn in $unformatted; do
    echo >&2 "  gofmt -w $PWD/$fn"
done

exit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the exit code to be 1 if fails, and to be able to run it on Linux or Mac or other Unix OS, you can use:

```
files=$(gofmt -l .) && [ -z "$files" ]
```